# SAML authentication in OpenSerch giving error "Could not find IDPSSODescriptor" with keycloak

Tags: amazon-web-services, keycloak, saml-2.0, opensearch

I am getting error below while integrating keycloak with OpenSearch (kibana). Is there any settings needed on keycloak side?  The error says "Could not find IDPSSODescriptor" but its clearly there in xml.

Error:

```
Could not find IDPSSODescriptor supporting SAML 2.0 in <instance name>; role descriptors: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata. impl.SPSSODescriptorImpl"
__AMAZON_INTERNAL__
__AMAZON_INTERNAL__
__AMAZON_INTERNAL__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting AWS hosted opensearch cluster resolved the issue.

Comment: How had you set up keycloak?